# Overflow conflict with absolute position inside float

Tags: html, css

There is a 'container' with overflow: auto that contains groups of floated elements, 'value'. Inside 'value', there is an absolute positioned element, 'popup' which gets cut off by the overflow. How can I make 'popup' show up and still keep 'container' from losing its layout?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="group">
    <span class="label">Label</span>
    <span class="value">
      <span class="popup_container">
        <div class="popup">Popup</div>
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <span class="label">Label</span>
    <span class="value">
      <span class="popup_container">
        <div class="popup">Popup</div>
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: red;
}
.label {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 100px;
}
.value {
    float: left;
}
.popup_container {
    position: relative;
}
.popup {
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/KA7AB/2/

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Set your popup_container to absolute:

```
position: absolute;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KA7AB/6/

Comment: Thanks, but I can't set it to absolute because there could be many fields inside the container each with their own popups.

Comment: Why?  I mean, what is the semantics of the content such that popups must be nested?

Comment: I was trying to simplify the css, but I guess it lost some of it's meaning. Each group is really a label value pair. The group value has a view and edit mode. The popup is displayed when in edit mode. I omitted the view part for simplicity but it should not have any affect on the problem here. See my edited post.